# NamedPipe binary messages

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

Simple question (details follow) : how to use named pipes, without soap serialization, i just want to have on method and read the byte array myself. I'm trying to implement a service that does not rely on XML, through named pipes.

Few weeks ago, i wrote a service using wcf and web sockets. This service, to deal with non .net software, use a custom binding with a really simple contract :

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    Task Message(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message);
```

and the callback :

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    Task OnMessage(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message result);
```

In this case, i just read the byte array and deserialize using protobuf.

I've got another service on the same machine, and i want to improve performence using the protobuf deserializer. This service is already exposed with named pipes (with our former contracts).

With the new websocket server, and the protobuf serializer, i would like to implement it on the second service. Looking at protobuf endpoint behavior, it seems that they override the XmlObjectSerializer, but it seems that it still use some xml.

Do anyone have an idea on how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You may be trying to overthink this. Named pipes (NetNamedPipeBinding) already use a binary message format, and should be fast, for on-machine communication. I don't know why you think you need to use protobuf. Make sure you are using the NetNamedPipeBinding first and measure the performance before you do anything else.

Comment: Yes i'm already using named pipe binding, with standard contract serialization. The fact is the datas transferred is longer, and the serialization/deserialization time is longer than protobuf, read this for more information http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.fr/2012/05/wcf-bindings.html

Comment: Reading this article shows that protobuf endpoint behavior still use soap for message envelop and data type resolution. In my case i just want to receive a byte array containing the information i sent with the server. Is that possible ?